# The OS shows rendered files as TextEdit Documents instead of PNGs

Tags: rendering, blend-files, file-browser

Using the new 2.90 version, I made a simple animation using some cloths sims and rendered it out in PNG images. When I check the images inside my file browser (Both the Blender file browser and the native MacOS file browser) I see that they are not PNG images. My mac instead says that they are TextEdit Documents.

When I open the image, it opens normally inside the "Preview" app (the default mac app for opening images). Sometimes it opens inside the TextEdit app and it shows me a bunch of garbled text.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the files have no extension. The OS doesn't know what kind of files they are, or what program to open them with, so it shows the files as text files (the default icon for unknown file formats).

Rename the files to be *.png

In blender enable File extensions.

[image]